# Django Parler also shows translated object on the admin list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-parler

I use Django 2.2.11 and Django-parler 2.0.1.

I created a model using TranslatableModel and TranslatableAdmin. Then I created an object and filled the translatable fields of the same object for the second language. When I get to the model list page, I see two objects in the list for the same object. Although two objects appear on the list, 1 object is written at the bottom of the list. (As you can see on the screenshot below)

I also got the same result as Django 2.0.7 and Django-parler 1.9.2.

Where could I have made a mistake, can someone help?

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you've solved it out because I'm facing the same problem???